# resize image with activitytresult

Tags: android

how to resize image with my below code ? the code get image but I didnt how to resize it.

```
   @Override
           protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

               super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

                    //file name
                    filePath = data.getData();
                    try {
                    //  Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
                        bitmap  = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                      //  imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                       byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();

                      Intent i = new Intent(this,
                                AddImage.class);
                      i.putExtra("image", imageInByte);
                      startActivity(i);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
           }
```

I read a so queston using this way , but its different then my way

```
File dir=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
Bitmap b= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PATH_ORIGINAL_IMAGE);
Bitmap out = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 320, 480, false);

File file = new File(dir, "resize.png");
FileOutputStream fOut;
try {
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
    b.recycle();
    out.recycle();               
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you that first set the bitmap image to imageview and apply scale i.e., resize as per your requirement using setScaleType method.

ex:
imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);

(or)

If you want to try in same way then I think this link may be help full.

https://argillander.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/scale-image-into-imageview-then-resize-imageview-to-match-the-image/

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am taking the image from sd card (as shown above) then send it as an intent to another activity and set it in image view. so you are saying after seting it in the image view then resize it ?

Answer (score 0):

To tell the decoder to subsample the image, loading a smaller version into memory, set inSampleSize to true in your BitmapFactory.Options object. For example, an image with resolution 2048x1536 that is decoded with an inSampleSize of 4 produces a bitmap of approximately 512x384. Loading this into memory uses 0.75MB rather than 12MB for the full image (assuming a bitmap configuration of ARGB_8888). Here’s a method to calculate a sample size value that is a power of two based on a target width and height:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: thanks for your asnwer , so this one will decrease the size of the image right ? my image size is aabout 200kb I want to make it 50kb,

Comment: It will not make effect image quality , aspect ratio, or memroy leak ?

Comment: no it will reduce the image resolution and indirectly reduces the image size, if you want to reduce the file size and not the image resolution then convert it to JPEG,

Comment: if your imageview resolution is less than the image resolution then you should be using the insamplesize to reduce the resolution that way you wont be loading the whole image into memory but a down sized sample of it

Comment: its jpg , this is the [link](http://www.justedhak.comlu.com/images/uploaded_images.jpg) of the photo if you save it , youll notice its 200kb I want to make it about 50kb or less but the quality stay the same .

Comment: tell me the resolution in dp of the imageView, why are you giving the compressFormat as png if you want jpg?

Comment: bhargav its 520dp , and yes its mistake ill fixed to jepg, but the image is saved as jpeg

Comment: pass your target width and height to this method and see what you get, try it for yourself

Comment: sorry stupid question ,, but I should add the method after this ? 
                           bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JEPG, 100, stream);

calculateInSampleSize( bitmap,520, 520);

Comment: I got this error ... The method calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options, int, int) in the type MainActivity is not applicable for the arguments (Bitmap, int, int) , what i should add in the function

Comment: you are supposed to pass `BitmapFactory.Options()` not `Bitmap` and update the `options.inSampleSize = whatever this method returns` in the class where u call this method